prologue in x64 windows - more parameters
I compile the following code in Visual Studio in 64-bit format:
int func1(int a, int b,int c, int d) {
    int res = 0;
    return res;
}

int main() {
    int p = 0;
    p = func1(1,2,3,4);
    return 0;
}

and open it in x64dbg:
sub rsp,38
mov dword ptr ss:[rsp+20],0
mov r9d,4
mov r8d,3
mov edx,2
mov ecx,1
call <prolog_epilog_64bit.int __cdecl func1(int, int, int, int)>
mov dword ptr ss:[rsp+20],eax
xor eax,eax
add rsp,38
ret 

I understand why 38 :
return add
---------------
8 byte
---------------
4 * 8 = 32=20h for register(fast call)
---------------
4 byte for int
---------------
12 (Stack alignment in x64)

8+20+4+c=38

Now I have this code:
int func2(int a, int b,int c, int d,int e) {
    int res = 0;
    return res;
}

int main() {
    int p = 0;
    p = func2(1,2,3,4,5);
    return 0;
}

and open it in x64dbg:
sub rsp,48
mov dword ptr ss:[rsp+30],0
mov dword ptr ss:[rsp+20],5
mov r9d,4
mov r8d,3
mov edx,2
mov ecx,1
call <prolog_epilog_64bit.int __cdecl func2(int, int, int, int, int)>
mov dword ptr ss:[rsp+30],eax
xor eax,eax
add rsp,48
ret 

return add
---------------
8 byte
---------------
4 * 8 = 32=20h for register(fast call)
---------------
8 byte for stack parameters
----------------------
4 byte for int local var
---------------
4 byte (Stack alignment in x64)

8 + 20 + 8 + 4 + 4=38

Why 48?
Should there be spaces between local variables and parameters passed on the stack? If we increase the number of parameters of the MAIN function (2 parameters), it does not change. (48)
I expected to see a value of 38 here as well, but it didn't.
why RSP+30 and RSP+20?

Looks like you have not enabled optimization in which case don't expect good code. Notice that even the first code uses too much stack space since it has 20 wasted bytes...

Should there be spaces between local variables and parameters passed on the stack? - There don't have to be, but RSP has to be aligned by 16 before a call, and stack args go directly above the shadow space.  Compile with optimization enabled on https://godbolt.org/ as in How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?.  (And use __attribute__((noipa)) for GCC or maybe some kind of _declspec(noinline) for MSVC, or simply write a function that calls a function you've only provided a prototype for instead of a definition, so it can't inline.)

The compiler only have to respect the stack alignment of the calling convention and make enough space for the shadow area and the parameters. It doesn't have to be the exact, minimum, amount that satisfies these conditions. In fact, most compiler will use an upper bound, sparing complexing in the stack allocation logic (at the cost of a few bytes of memory). Don't look too much into it, it's just "enough space, often more that it's needed" situation.
